# Loosing a route value named action in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

Something weird happened when I was creating a link using MVC: aspx view:

```
<%= Url.Action("ActionName", "Controller", new { action = "add" }) %>
```

While I expected: `"/Controller/ActionName?action=add"`,
I got just: `"/Controller/ActionName"`.

I guess it's because of 'action' route map??

Any way to force this? Any Documentation? For I'm wondering what else gets stripped.

**Route config:**

```
routes.MapRoute("Default", 
  "{controller}/{action}/{id}", 
  new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }
);
```

Comment: What is your route table?  Looks like you are doubling up the action in the url and query string.

Comment: Default: `routes.MapRoute("Default", "{controller}/{action}/{id}", new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" });`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`action` (or any casing of that) is reserved route data, critical to ASP.NET MVC. I would suggest renaming that to something else.

Under the covers, the `Url.Action` helper is likely overriding it with the value of the `actionName` parameter.

Other reserved route data names include `controller` and `area`. These, too, are case-insensitive.

Comment: Thanks, any documentation on this behavior?

Comment: Ended up changing the name of the variable. Makes me wonder if I have overlooked this before.